# Is there a systematic way to compute the receptive field of a neuron?

Tags: tensorflow

I am interested in computing the receptive field of a neuron relatively to the input, or more generally relatively to an earlier layer.

This can be done manually, but I would like to know if there is a built-in function to do it or otherwise if there is a way do compute it automatically.

Is there something that could work at least on a simple (single stream, no skip/concatenation) network restricted to convolutions and reduce layers, with possibly a mix of `SAME` and `VALID` paddings and non-unit strides?

Comment: As of 2017 tensorflow proper doesn't have a built-in function to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of Aug 2017, you can simply use `tf.contrib.receptive_field`

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/receptive_field for details.

Comment: Above link giving 404 error...can you please help out any other resource